# The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data

Tags: ios, swift, photolibrary, phphotolibrary

I have added NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription as well as NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription in info.plist file of my project.
While trying to create album or add image to photo library following error is coming

**This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.**

I have tried some swift library like [PhotosHelper](https://github.com/DroidsOnRoids/PhotosHelper).as well to do that but still I am facing same Issue

Following is code that I am following

```
import UIKit
import Photos

class PhotoLibraryManager
{


private class func fetchAlbumWithName(albumName:String)->PHAssetCollection?
{
    let fetchPredicate = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchPredicate.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title == '" + albumName + "'")
    let fetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: PHAssetCollectionType.album, subtype: PHAssetCollectionSubtype.albumRegular, options: fetchPredicate)
    return fetchResult.firstObject
}

/**
 This function requests for authorization to use the photo gallery and adds the image in the album both of which are specified.If the album does not exist it creates a new one and adds the image in that
 - Parameters:
 - image:The image to be inserted
 - albumName:The name of the album in which the image is to be inserted
 */


class func saveImageToPhone(image:UIImage,albumName:String)
{
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({(status:PHAuthorizationStatus)->Void in
        switch status
        {
        case PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized:
            insertImageAfterAuthorization(image: image,albumName: albumName)
        default:
            print("Unable To Access Photo Library")
        }
    })
}

/**
 This function fetches the specified album from the photo library if present or creates a new one
 - Parameters:
 - image:The image to be inserted
 - albumName:The name of the album in which the image is to be inserted
 */


private class func insertImageAfterAuthorization(image:UIImage,albumName:String)
{
    let album = fetchAlbumWithName(albumName: albumName)
    guard let albumToBeInserted = album else{
        print("Creating A New Album \(albumName)")
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollection(withTitle: albumName)
        }, completionHandler: {(success:Bool,error:Error?)->Void in
            guard let errorObj = error else{
                let album = fetchAlbumWithName(albumName: albumName)
                guard let createdAlbum = album else{
                    print("Album Not Created")
                    return
                }
                addImageIntoAlbum(image: image,album: createdAlbum)
                return
            }
            print(errorObj.localizedDescription)
            return
        })
        return
    }
    addImageIntoAlbum(image: image,album: albumToBeInserted)
}

/**
 This function adds an image into the album specifed
 - Parameters:
 - image:The image to be added
 - album:The album in which the image is to inserted
 */

private class func addImageIntoAlbum(image:UIImage,album:PHAssetCollection)
{
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        let imgCreationRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image)
        print(imgCreationRequest)
        let albumRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: album)
        guard let albumSpecificationRequest = albumRequest , let placeholderObjForImg = imgCreationRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset else{
            print("Image Could Not Be Added")
            return
        }
        let arrAlbumSpecificationRequest:NSArray = [placeholderObjForImg]
        albumSpecificationRequest.addAssets(arrAlbumSpecificationRequest)
        //            albumSpecificationRequest.addAssets([placeholderObjForImg])
    }, completionHandler: {(success:Bool,error:Error?)->Void in
        guard let errorObj = error else{
            return
        }
        print(errorObj.localizedDescription)
    })
}

}
```

Here is my info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>NewApp</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1</string>
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>armv7</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
<string>Connect People</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Video Call</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>For Audio Call</string>
<key>NSSiriUsageDescription</key>
<string>Siri Uses Test</string>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
    <string>voip</string>
</array>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Photo Use</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>Photo Use</string>
<key>NSUserActivityTypes </key>
<array>
    <string>INStartAudioCallIntent</string>
    <string>INStartVideoCallIntent</string>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: So, did you add NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key in info.plist?

Comment: Update your question showing the relevant portion of your Info.plist.

Comment: It's probably a plist issue not a code issue. As rmaddy said, please show your plist.

Comment: What's the string value you added for NSCameraUsageDescription?

Comment: I have updated questions with info.plist file

Comment: "Video Call" String Value I added to NSCameraUsageDescription

Comment: Check if it's correct Info.plist. Some projects have a few.

Comment: Make sure there's no extra space also, it could be consider wrong key and it won't works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have fixed the issue, I don't know what was the reason. after so much of struggle, I got idea to try in different project so,  I created a new project and copy info.plist & other required swift and story bored files from old project to new project & it works.

Answer (score 7):

Open your info.plist as a source code and paste the following in it.

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string>

<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires read and write access to the photo library.</string>
```

Answer (score 4):

Open your `info.plist` by `Source Code` or `Property List`.

For `Property List`,you can just add a key `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` and its value `This app requires access to the photo library.`

For `Source Code`,you can add the follow code to the plist.And the code must be between the `<dict>` and the `</dict>`.

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string>
```

The value for the key is actually a kind of desctription, so you can make a description all by youself.But make sure that the users of your app can understand the description you make easily.

And for camera,you can use the follow code:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the camera.</string>
```

More keys: [Cocoa keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html).